# How to give equal margin to inner div?

Tags: html, css, css-float

How we can make inner div have equal margins from outer div from all four sides?

Here's what I've tried:

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
    A
</div>
</div>
```

My styles:

```
div
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.outer{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: gainsboro;
}

.inner{
    background-color: wheat;
    margin: 5px;    
}
```

Note: I want to achieve this with pure CSS + I don't want to do something like this:

```
.inner{
    height: 90px;
}
```

or

```
.inner{
    height: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Your solutions in *i dont want to do somthing like this* are Pure CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give inner div top, bottom, left and right.  this will make the spacing between it and the outer one.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Bla!
        </title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            div { overflow:hidden; }
            div.outer {height:100px; width:100px; background-color:gainsboro; position:absolute} 
            div.outer >div {top:5px; left:5px; right:5px; bottom:5px; position:absolute; background-color: wheat;} 
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='outer'>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using this solution, the outer you may get any block definitions that make sizes (relative, fixed, etc.). the inner should have the absolute sized (it's inside the outer).

Comment: I've not tested this, but shouldn't `div.outer` be `position:relative`?

Answer (score 1):

Give `padding` to `.outer`.

Try:

```
.outer{
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color: gainsboro;
}
.inner{
    background-color: wheat;        
    height:100%;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/AzZtu/)

Comment: it is reverse to .inner{
    height: 90px;
}

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have weird wishes as you do not want to use `height` property, so the only way left is to use `display: table;` for parent element and `display: table-cell;` for child element. And since `td` element won't take `margin` am using `padding` on parent element with `box-sizing` property set to `border-box` so that it will count the `padding` inside instead of outside the element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/66bkm/)

```
div
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.outer{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    display: table;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
}

.inner{
    background-color: wheat;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Dum... What if inner div's content exceed's 100px height:)?

Comment: Dum... What if inner div's content exceed's 100px height:)?

Comment: @MackMon Well, you have too much of conditions, it would be better if you use `height` for the child `div` as anyways you do not want to expand, I gave this solution, and not `absolute` cuz I thought you needed an expanding element, but with `height` upto `100%` maintaining `margin` so if you know there's a fixed `height` so use it on the child element

Comment: @MackMon and trust me, that's a perfect solution

Comment: Since my outer is responsive for browser height, i could not go on changing the height of my inner div. So need some more solutions so could get some better sln..

Comment: @MackMon this is all I have, and probably you won't get any apart from this using PURE CSS

Comment: @MackMon it's all same